# How to stop getopts from taking blank or null or other options as option value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopt, getopts

I (presumably everyone) hit by this problem time to time but couldn't find any good workaround by myself. When `getopts` looks for an argument, it literally takes the next one, even if it's an option. This is what I did to stop that (code snippet):

```
#!/bin/bash 

function optsGet()
{
    while getopts ":c:f" opt; do
        case $opt in
            c ) [[ -z "${OPTARG}" || "${OPTARG}" == -* ]] \
                && { echo -e "ERROR: Invalid argument\n"; exit 1; }
                CNAME="${OPTARG}.tEsTsTr"
                ;;
            f ) FORCE=true
                ;;
            \?) echo -e "Invalid option: -$OPTARG\n" >&2;;
            : ) echo -e "Missing argument for -$OPTARG\n" >&2; exit 1;;
            * ) echo -e "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG\n" >&2; exit 1;;
        esac
    done

    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
}

optsGet "${@}"
echo -e "CNAME: ${CNAME}\n"
```

but it is still taking blank/null as a valid argument. So, this works:

```
san@AM0150 testtools$ ./getopts.sh -c -f
ERROR: Invalid argument
```

But these aren't:

```
san@AM0150 testtools$ ./getopts.sh -c " " -f
CNAME:  .tEsTsTr

san@AM0150 testtools$ ./getopts.sh -c \  -f
CNAME:  .tEsTsTr
```

I was rather expecting `Missing argument for -c` error. Is there anything I'm missing here? Or does anyone know workaround? Any input will be highly appreciate. Cheers!!

---

**Update (mainly based on *devnull*'s reply):**

Just for the completeness, now I have this little function:

```
function ifEmpty()
{
    local VAL=$1
    local OPT=$2

    [[ -z "${VAL}" || "${VAL}" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ || "${VAL}" == -* ]] \
    && { echo -e "\n  ERROR: Missing argument for option: -${OPT}\n" >&2; exit 1; }
}
```

then this can be used like this:

```
c ) ifEmpty "${OPTARG}" "${opt}"
    CNAME=${OPTARG//[[:space:]]}
    ;;
```

for all the options that needs an argument. Cheers!!

PS. for some reason, `*[[:space:]]*` doesn't work when used in the function.

Comment: `" "` isn't the same as `""`, ie. isn't an empty string (it has a space in it). If you're looking to strip leading spaces, you can do that

Comment: @John Kugelman: You are absolutely right but maybe that's not the most used case scenario. Well, in that case, you just don't use that thing. Cheers!!

Comment: You can play around with this script: `while getopts "f:c" arg;
do
    echo "$arg: $OPTARG";
done;
shift $((OPTIND-1));
printf "Arg: %s\n" "$@"` with various option sequences.  Note that if you type `./test-getopts.sh -f -- -c`, the `-f` gets the double-dash as the option argument.  It is a simple rule that `getopts` (and the underlying `getopt()` function) implements; it isn't always what people want.  The excuse that `--` might be a file name is pretty thin; if you wanted to specify a file name in the current directory consisting of two dashes, you could/should write `./--`, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-z` would return true for an empty string, not for a string containing *spaces*.

Check if the string consists only of whitespaces.  Say:

```
    c ) [[ -z "${OPTARG}" || "${OPTARG}" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ || "${OPTARG}" == -* ]] \
```

instead of

```
    c ) [[ -z "${OPTARG}" || "${OPTARG}" == -* ]] \
```

This would also handle the null (`\`) case.

`EDIT:` In fact, it can also be written as:

```
    c ) [[ -z "${OPTARG}" || "${OPTARG}" == *[[:space:]]* || "${OPTARG}" == -* ]] \
```

Comment: Thanks devnull! I think I'll go with `^[[:space:]]*$`. One downside with `[[:space:]]*` is: it also considers `"     test"` as an invalid argument, which may or may not be true in some cases. Cheers!!

Comment: Ah! there's a typo in the last one.  It should read `*[[:space:]]*` instead.  Edited above.

Comment: The change would fix the `" test"` issue you mentioned.

Comment: yes! it did indeed but I had to use `=~` in stead of `==`. cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

This may be a non-answer answer, but I would not try to stop it. If `-c` takes a file name as an argument, say, `-f` could be a valid file name, as could   (a space). As a general rule I don't think shell scripts should do "helpful" things like trimming whitespace or throwing out unusual-but-technically-valid arguments.